# How to set a text value for document.activeElement?

Tags: javascript, html, input, xul

Knowing that my `document.activeElement` is an input field (I don't know exactly the name of the component, but may be the Google's search input field, for example), how can I set a text on it programmatically?

**--update**

I'm trying it from a xul application, via javascript after the page is loaded. A paste command works fine, so I know the field have the focus. (and I didn't put the Xul tag becouse it's just about the javascript)

Comment: The answers using document.activeElement.value should work - check out http://jsfiddle.net/FEKZj/.  If that's not working for you in a specific scenario, there's probably something else going on.  Could you please post all of your code where you're having the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's a little more trouble because I'm in a Xul app. Javascript was supposed to work like in the browsers, but it didn't.

What I did to make it work was (after put the content in the clipboard):

```
controller.doCommand('cmd_selectAll');
controller.doCommand('cmd_paste');
```

Answer (score 5):

See the [mozilla reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.activeElement). This is the same type as `document.getElementById()`

```
document.activeElement.value = 'new value';
```

Comment: @Tom Brito - well are you trying to do this through the console or what? It worked for me through the console in chrome.

Comment: From a xul application, via javascript after the page is loaded. A paste command works fine, so I know the field has the focus.

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure it is a input text field, just set the value:

```
document.activeElement.value = 'value'
```

Comment: @Tom Brito No, it doesn't, because Google does weird AJAX stuff with its text box. Try it with the SO search box.

Comment: @lonesomeday it didn't work either. Even if we make it work here, isn't there a way for it to work in any input field of any website?

Comment: Sure, use jQuery and execute this:

     $(":input").val('value for every input field');

Comment: no success. I think there's a little more trouble because I'm in a Xul app. Javascript was supposed to work like in the browsers, but it didn't.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code and the context it is running in, I can only speculate.  However, my guess is that you are calling `document.activeElement` from your XUL app, which means `document` is the chrome document, not the content page.  In this case, the active element is likely to be the `browser` or `iframe` element you are using to display the content.

Comment: I'm using a browser element inside a window element. IMO, if my active element will always be the browser, it should be considered a bug in Xulrunner. But I think I have no way to be sure of what element it is.

Comment: It's not a bug.  You are asking for the activeElement of a document.  Your document contains a xul:browser.  If you want the active element in the browser, use the contentDocument property on the browser, and access it's activeElement. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/browser#p-contentDocument)

Comment: @sdwilsh: I got `Error: document.activeElement.contentDocument is undefined`, looks like my activeElement is something else.. but I have only a browser element on the window (later intend to add more stuff, so I need the browser element instead of using the window itself to load the page)

Comment: Also, use the @Tom Brito notation, so the comment will appear in my summary.. :)

Comment: @Tom Brito How about document.getElementById("browser-id").contentDocument.activeElement?

Comment: @sdwilsh I'm doing a generic script, for many windows. I can't use a single browser id, becouse it will be one for each window. I need to get the abstract current window's browser.

Comment: @Tom Brito document.getElementsByTagName("browser")[0]?

Comment: @sdwilsh too coupled.. would be difficult to have 2 browsers in a window, but not impossible. I don't think it's a good approach. But could work fine if I need a workaround to show for my boss tomorrow.. :) keep commenting new ideas.

Comment: @Tom Brito sadly, I think I'm out of ideas :/

Answer (score 0):

If you want the focused element wherever it may be relative to the given application window, e.g. it may be inside a `<browser>` element, use `document.commandDispatcher.focusedElement.value` which is the same as `document.commandDispatcher.focusedWindow.document.activeElement.value`. This gives you the element that `cmd_paste` operates on.

Comment: I tried to set this `value` both as property and attribute, but nothing happened here. I don't know how the paste work with it.